# MySQL / PHP - performance - cache or live queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing listing for my gallery (using next / prev). Problem is, that if I select next/prev with every change of foto, query takes up to 0.1 s. That is bad, considering two things
a) Vistors will be browsing gallery pretty much 
b) Rest of my queries is in time os 0.005s

But If I select all IDs of fotos in one query, I got lets say 1000 results (time of query is about 0.15s). I can built tree from those and find easily next / prev within it. But it takes memory. On my server, I have problems with performance (CPU, not memory), so it will be probably better solution. Am I right ?

And if so, how or where can I store that tree ? I can have many different ones, because all images are in one table and browsing is per user (eg. their uploaded fotos) and with different ordering (time, type, score...). So I can´t cache all trees beforehead, it will be just huge (and it can change, while different users are uploading fotos almost instantly). I though of building new tree for every user, when he opens specific gallery. Storing it in SESSION seems "stupid", because thats not optimised for such a thing.. is tehre something else ?

Comment: Wouldn't indexes on gallery table be nice?

Comment: Of course, I have indexes

Answer (score 0):

Often, the MySQL query cache is a quick way to make `SELECT` queries faster. The query cache will save the results of recent queries and return them when the same query is repeated. That means, that after the first time you run a query, subsequent identical queries will be much faster. The query cache does not return stale data. When tables are modified, any relevant entries in the query cache are flushed.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

To check whether the query cache is being used, execute the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_type';
```

If the value is `OFF` or `0`, add these two lines to your MySQL configuration:

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 64M
```

Afterwards, restart your MySQL server.